# Как восстановить сайт из recovery mode WordPress? Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Обновил плагин Premium Addons for Elementor до последней версии, что вызвало критическую ошибку на сайте. Вошел в recovery mode, там пишет такую ошибку:

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 911 of the file
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/includes/helper-functions.php.
> Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> is_feature_active() on null in  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/includes/helper-functions.php:911 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/modules/premium-equal-height/module.php(62): PremiumAddons\Includes\Helper_Functions::check_elementor_experiment('container') #1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/modules/premium-equal-height/module.php(321): PremiumAddons\Modules\Premium_Equal_Height\Module->__construct() #2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/includes/addons-integration.php(1116): PremiumAddons\Modules\Premium_Equal_Height\Module::get_instance() #3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/includes/addons-integration.php(109): PremiumAddons\Includes\Addons_Integration->load_pa_extensions() #4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/premium-addons-for-elementor/includes/addons-integration.php(1147): PremiumAddons\Includes\Addons_Inte

Есть кнопка resume, я ее боюсь жать. Как откатиться на прошлую версию плагина или исправить ошибку?

Comment: Переименуйте папку с плагином, тогда у вас все должно заработать. После чего скачайте нужную версию плагина и установите. Или же просто восстановите бэкап в хостинг-панели, если таковой имеется

Comment: @rusgeli а где взять старую версию?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH наверное там где брали и последнюю. Проще всего просто восстановиться из бекапа.